# Why don't have content when using Custom UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I create a table view programmatically, and custom its cell

in `TheCell.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TheCell: UITableViewCell {
  var takeTime: UILabel = UILabel()

  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.addSubview(takeTime)
  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
  }

  override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    takeTime = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100,height:40))
    takeTime.textColor = .lightGray
  }
}
```

and in table view, I use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as? TheCell
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = TheCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    cell?.takeTime.text = "23:23"
    return cell!
}
```

I thought I can get a list of time `23:23`, but there's nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of adding `takeTime` as a cell subview like this: `self.addSubview(takeTime)` add it as a subview of the cell contentView: `contentView.addSubview(takeTime)`

Also, in `layoutSubviews` just set frame of the label: 
`takeTime.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:100,height:40)`